# Csv file to an array

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a csv file which contains the following values:

```
18/10/2013,  news item 1
18/10/2013,  news item 2
17/10/2013,  news item 3
16/10/2013,  news item 4
```

How do I go about putting this into an array in JavaScript, ordered by date?

Once I have got it into an array, I also need to get the text values.

So far I have something like this:

```
Function readTextFile(){

var rawFile = new XMLhttpRequest();
Var myArray;

rawFile.open("GET", csvfile, true);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(rawFile.readyState === 4){
  if(rawFile.Status === 200 || rawFile.Status === 0)
{

}
}
}
```

Sorry if the text above is not formatted properly, I am posting from my phone. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript code to parse CSV data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it.

```
Function readTextFile(){

var rawFile = new XMLhttpRequest();
Var myArray;

rawFile.open("GET", csvfile, true);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(rawFile.readyState === 4){
  if(rawFile.Status === 200 || rawFile.Status === 0)
{
    var response = rawFile.responseText;
    var splitData = new Array();
     //split data with new line

    splitData = response.split("\n");    //stores all the values separated by new line
    console.log(splitData[0]);      //returns   18/10/2013,  news item 1

  //split single line data with comma 

    var splitComma = new Array();
    var splitComma = splitData[0].split(",");  
    console.log(splitComma[0]);          //returns  18/10/2013

   //start comparing date values here

}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = rawFile.responseText.split(",");
```

But it will not sort the data according to login date